# GNOME topbar on secondary monitor

Tags: gnome

I use GNOME 40.5 and I would like to ask you how can I add GNOME topbar to secondary monitor too.

This is my desktop:

[image: Desktop]

and as you can see I don't have topbar on secondary monitor, I would like to have clock and system tray here.

Comment: probably not, though I dont know what Actual bar is , it is not in the gnome extension search. https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/35

Comment: try this method https://github.com/realh/multi-monitors-add-on.git i hope help you